# TinyMCE updating Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, tinymce

I am having some trouble with the updating of a database field using TinyMCE.

The TinyMCE displays everything absolutely fine from my database (exactly what I want it to), so I know it is connecting.

My problem is the fact that when I try and update the content and save it to my database it either fails or updates the database with a blank slate, can anyone help me with this?

Javascript on update/tinymce page:

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea",
            toolbar: 'styleselect | bold underline italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | link image | media | forecolor backcolor', 
            plugins: [ 
                'advlist autolink link lists charmap preview', 
                'searchreplace wordcount code media', 
                'save textcolor'
            ]
        });
```

Form to update from tinymce:

```
function contentChange(){
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['title']);
$sqlCommand = "(SELECT * FROM mainContent WHERE title='$title')";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCommand) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
$column = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

echo "<form method='post' action='processes/contentChangeProcess.php?title=".$title."' style='height:600px;background:transparent;'>
        <textarea id='contentUpdate' name='contentUpdate' style='height:600px;background:transparent;'>
            ".$column['content']."
        </textarea><br />
        <input style='box-shadow:0px 0px 5px 0px #000;width:100%;height:40px;font-weight:normal;font-size:20pt;' id='contentChangeSubmit' type='submit' name='contentChangeSubmit' value='Save Content' />
    </form>";

mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Updating/processing page:

```
function contentChangeProcess(){
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_GET['title']);

if(isset($_POST['contentChangeSubmit'])){
    $contentUpdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['contentUpdate']);

    if(!IsInjected($contentUpdate)){
        $con=mysqli_connect("","","","");
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE mainContent SET content='$contentUpdate' WHERE title='$title'");
        echo "Successfully updated.<br /><br /> <a href='http://www.dream-fitness.com/pages/contentChange.php?title=".$title."'>Update Same Page</a><br /><a href='http://www.dream-fitness.com/pages/".$title.".php'>View Page Change</a><br /><br /><a href='http://www.dream-fitness.com/pages/userAccount.php'>Go back to user account</a>";
    }else{
        echo "Woops, you entered something weird!<br /><br />";
        echo "Failed to update.<br /><br /> <a href='http://www.dream-fitness.com/pages/contentChange.php?title=".$title."'>Retry Update Same Page</a><br /><a href='http://www.dream-fitness.com/pages/".$title.".php'>View Page Change</a><br /><br /><a href='http://www.dream-fitness.com/pages/userAccount.php'>Go back to user account</a>";
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: fails HOW? you get an sql error? You never bother checking the return value of your update query, so you're simply ASSUMING the query succeeds. That's bad coding, especially since you already have an `or die(...)` on your original select query.

Comment: @MarcB Woops sorry, it fails by going straight into my ELSE in the updating page. I haven't assumed the query succeeds, I have been playing around with it left, right and center to work it and have looked up all over the internet, the code was updating my content field with nothing and then failed through into the ELSE after I changed some code. If you have no good information to get me onto the right track then do not leave a comment, thank you.

Comment: Show us input that goes to the else that shouldn't. Also show us input that goes to the if but leaves your row's column empty. Also die when your update query fails `or die(mysqli_error())`.

Comment: @LoganMurphy Thank you for helping, just went and took out ! from !IsInjected in my if statement in updating page, not great but at least I know it is working, thank you anyway

Comment: @sBradford-Smith that edit is not going to help debug at all. Try `echo htmlspecialchars($contentUpdate);` in the `else` and `or die(mysqli_error($con))` in the `if` and tell us the output and why it is wrong.